# Export AVAsset with fading by AVAudioMix

Tags: ios, xcode, avfoundation

The task is to trim audio asset and make fade effect. Here is my code:

```
+ (void)exportAsset:(AVAsset *)asset trimTimeRange:(CMTimeRange)trimTimeRange fadeDuration:(CMTime)fadeDuration
{
    NSArray *tracks = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
    AVAssetTrack *track = [tracks objectAtIndex:0];

    CMTimeRange fadeInTimeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(trimTimeRange.start, fadeDuration);

    AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *exportAudioMixFadeInInputParameters = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParametersWithTrack:track];
    [exportAudioMixFadeInInputParameters setVolumeRampFromStartVolume:0.0 toEndVolume:1.0 timeRange:fadeInTimeRange];

    CMTime startFadeOutTime = CMTimeMake(trimTimeRange.start.value + trimTimeRange.duration.value - fadeDuration.value, 1000);
    CMTimeRange fadeOutTimeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(startFadeOutTime, fadeDuration);

    AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *exportAudioMixFadeOutInputParameters = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParametersWithTrack:track];
    [exportAudioMixFadeOutInputParameters setVolumeRampFromStartVolume:1.0 toEndVolume:0.0 timeRange:fadeOutTimeRange];

    AVMutableAudioMix *exportAudioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
    exportAudioMix.inputParameters = @[exportAudioMixFadeOutInputParameters, exportAudioMixFadeInInputParameters];

    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", [PathHelper applicationDocumentsDirectory], filenameM4A];

    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [AVAssetExportSession exportSessionWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];
    exportSession.audioMix = exportAudioMix;
    exportSession.outputURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A;
    exportSession.timeRange = trimTimeRange;

    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:nil];
}
```

It's very strange, but if I pass input parameters for audio mix like this

```
exportAudioMix.inputParameters = @[exportAudioMixFadeInInputParameters, exportAudioMixFadeOutInputParameters];
```

I get 1st result (take a look at the picture)
If like this

```
exportAudioMix.inputParameters = @[exportAudioMixFadeOutInputParameters, exportAudioMixFadeInInputParameters];
```

I get 2nd result.
Looks like second parameter is ignoring. Can anyone explain this behavior?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I found solution. I shouldn't create different items of AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters for fade in and fade out. Here is my code:

```
CMTimeRange fadeInTimeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(trimTimeRange.start, fadeDuration);

CMTime startFadeOutTime = CMTimeMake(trimTimeRange.start.value + trimTimeRange.duration.value - fadeDuration.value, 1000);
CMTimeRange fadeOutTimeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(startFadeOutTime, fadeDuration);

AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *exportAudioMixInputParameters = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParametersWithTrack:track];
[exportAudioMixInputParameters setVolumeRampFromStartVolume:0.0 toEndVolume:1.0 timeRange:fadeInTimeRange];
[exportAudioMixInputParameters setVolumeRampFromStartVolume:1.0 toEndVolume:0.0 timeRange:fadeOutTimeRange];

AVMutableAudioMix *exportAudioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
exportAudioMix.inputParameters = [NSArray arrayWithObject:exportAudioMixInputParameters]];
```